# How can I fix issue "Content Encoding Error"

Tags: wordpress

My website is in wordpress that is midtb.org

I am getting "**Content Encoding Error**" on Firefox.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN6sy.png

And on Chrome get this screenshot error. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXSzI.png

I did not understand why I am getting this issues. Please guide me how can I resolve it.

Comment: It open at my side successfully

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar I have also checked it on 4 different pc. and this is not working :(

Comment: [check](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f35dmxh92) this screen capture

Comment: On my hand, on first hit it shows error, But on refresh the page. It loads the pages.

Comment: Try to clear the browser cache

Comment: I did but nothing happened